# Migrate site to SSL

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer, fbdev

I have just migrated my website from http to https. Now I can't use anymore the Facebook Sharing Debugger as I am always receiving this message: "*Could not scrape the URL because it was rate limited.*"

What can I do?
Thanks

Comment: Same thing is happening to me! According to my app dashboard, I have not made enough calls in the last 24 hours to qualify for rate limiting, which suggests it has nothing to do with my app but that Facebook has rate limited itself lol!

Comment: Scrape rate limit and API rate limit are two completely different things

Comment: No help or suggestions on this?